# AM circuit LTspice

Tags: ltspice, darlington, amplitude-modulation, phase-shift, 555

I have to analyze the following circuit and understand its function.

As far as I understand the top part is the simple phase-shift oscillator generating output sine wave at circa 145kHz.

The NE555 is an
monostable(?) multivibrator that generates square pulse. But what about transistors between them?

It looks like a Darlington circuit but I'm not sure and I also don't know how it works.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Some pictures of the simulation in LTspice below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where did the circuit come from? Doesn't the original source provide some explanations?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson unfortunately no. this is the part of assignment that I received at the university. We should analyze the netwokr(which is actually bigger than I showed here). I could find some info regarding other parts but nothing about the part I am asking about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, Q4 kills off the output from the phase-shift oscillator every time the 555 timer (low frequency oscillator) output goes low. Q4 acts as a short and basically "mutes" the output from Q1 and significantly disrupts the bias point of Q2 to turn it off.

Q4 is helped along the way with a buffer amplifier formed by Q3. It's likely that a single half-decent MOSFET could replace both Q3 and Q4.

> *It looks like Darlington Circuit*

No.